# Ad unit detection count | Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script where I want to check how many ad slots there are on a page. The way these slots are presented are like so:

```
//Adslot 1 declaration
    gptadslots[1]= googletag.defineSlot('/150185454/Express/Home', [[1,1],[728,90],[900,250],[970,250],[970,90]],'div-gpt-ad-783061624906669251-1').setTargeting('pos',['top']).setTargeting('gwd', [ASPQ_adlwo6]).addService(googletag.pubads());
```

There are 5 instances of this on my static page so here is my logic around this.

The only consistent variable I can see is the following number as part of `defineSlot` which is `"/150185454/"`. This is only defined within the `<head>` tag.

Here is my code so far which only covers the detection if there is an ad slot on the page:

```
var adUnit = '/150185454/',
    headContent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;

        if (headContent.indexOf(adUnit) >= 0) {
            console.log("UNIT IS ON THE PAGE");
        }
```

Expectation:

If `"/150185454/"` is within the head then get the rest of the URL which would look like this: `'/150185454/Express/Home'`. The "Express/Home" is a page path within the site - we want to know which page this ad slot was presented on.

Then take only the page path name (`'Express/Home'`)  and append to a tracking URL.

I'm having trouble getting the rest of the URL after `"/150185454/"`. I'm unsure how to achieve this as well as stripping the number to then append to the tracking URL which is posted.

I hope this is clear enough, please ask if more direction is needed.